# Excel - SUMIF based on a multi-select dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a nested SUMIF statement that sums data from Sheet2 based on criteria from drop-down list cells in the current sheet.

Cell A contains city names...

*---(If A2 = "Albuquerque", then it will sum the data for Albuquerque from Column A in Sheet2)*

Column B contains months...
*---(If B2 = "January 2019", then it will sum the data for January 2019 from Column B in Sheet2)*

The fundamental formula is...

```
 =IF(AND($A$2="",$B$2=""),SUM('Sheet 2'!J:J),IF(AND($A$2<>"",$B$2=""),SUMIF(Sheet 2'!A:A,A2,'Sheet 2'!J:J),IF(AND($A$2="",$B$2<>""),SUMIF(Sheet 2'!B:B,B2,'Sheet 2'!J:J),IF(AND($T$2<>"",$T$3<>""),SUMIFS('Sheet 2'!J:J,'Sheet 2'!A:A,A2,'Sheet 2'!B:B,B2))))
```

**This formula works so long as one value is selected for the drop-down list cell.**

But the drop-down lists have multi-select enabled with a comma separating both values. And if I select more than one item from the drop-down in the drop-down list cells, the SUMIFS formula doesn't understand and returns nothing.

*---i.e.: If I select Albuquerque and Phoenix in cell A2, A2 will show "Albuquerque, Phoenix". But the SUMIF will not recognize this and will return 0 instead of data for both Albuquerque and Phoenix.*

I'm wondering if there is a way to engineer my formula in a way that will recognize more than two items in the drop-down list cell and filter the data according to both of those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can iterate the comma separated values with:

```
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))
```

We can also move the IF into the SUMIFS to using `"*"` to return everything when blank.

We need to transpose the second array returned on the second drop down.  Two is the maximum comma delimited lists that can be used.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('Sheet 2'!J:J,'Sheet 2'!A:A,IF(A2="","*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))),'Sheet 2'!B:B,IF(B2="","*",TRANSPOSE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Scott, this is very impressive. I plugged it into my model to test it out and it doesn't give me any errors, which is remarkable. However, it does seem to return a far larger number than expected, and I think it might have to do with the SUMPRODUCT piece of the puzzle. My question is, why are we wrapping this in a SUMPRODUCT, and how did you get the number "5" in your example.

Comment: The SUMPRODUCT is necessary other wise it would only return the first match not iterate the lists.  As to it being to large, you will need to check it manually against what is being produced.  It works as desired for me.

Comment: I understand, this is very solid. For some reason it still doesn't recognize the second part of the drop-down cell, unfortunately. As in, if both Albequerque and Phoenix are present, it will return the correct answer for Albequerque, but exclude Phoenix. No worries. I'll try to figure this out on my own further. Thank you though!

Comment: @MiguelZaldivar it may have to do with the value in the cell not actually being what it is showing.  Try in a blank cell `=A2` and see if it trully is returning a comma delimited value.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you.